# Как получить случайное число 0f..1f?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть номер тика (по сути логический кадр), есть счетчик - количество обращений к методу за этот тик. Нужно получить случайное число 0f..1f исходя из этих двух чисел. У кого есть мысли?

Comment: а почему просто случайное число нельзя? или оно должно явно зависеть от этих 2 чисел?

Comment: @pavel Как я понимаю, да, результат должен быть привязан к входным данным.

Comment: а какие критерии на случайность? Просто тогда это будет обычная функция от 2 переменных)

Comment: Ага, с виду так и кажется. Думаю, возможно есть какие–то нюансы связанные с кадрами?

Comment: Ну можно передать эти числа в качестве зерна для рандома `new Random(num+cnt).Next(15,31)`.

Comment: Если бы можно было использовать системный rnd, то и вопроса бы не было)

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно просто случайное число в заданном диапазоне - тогда  [Random.Range(15, 31)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) (да, обе границы включаются).

Если же результат должен зависеть от входных данных, тогда это никакое не случайное число. Но можно придумать. Я бы взял два больших простых числа и сделал что то такое (t -  номер тика, n - кол-во обращений)

```
(t * 263 + n * 269 ) % 17 + 15
```

17 - это количество возможных значений (1f - 0f + 1), 15 - это стартовое значение.

Comment: Random.Range использовать нельзя, ибо мне необходимо чтобы на всех клиентах он выдавал одинаковое значение, что невозможно даже с seed'ом, ибо клиент 1 может позвать его 3 раза, а клиент 2 - 5 раз. Но оба клиента имеют 2 значения, которые точно одинаковые на обоих клиентах в конкретный момент времени. Детерминированная логика там.

Comment: Тогда правильный ответ - использовать любую функцию хеширования.

Answer (score 0):

Все, вопрос снят, решение найдено:

```
crt::uint32 _x;
crt::uint32 _y;
crt::uint32 _z;
crt::uint32 _w;

inline crt::uint32 RandGen::_next()
{
    crt::uint32 t = _x ^ (_x << 11);

    _x = _y;
    _y = _z;
    _z = _w;

    _w = (_w ^ (_w >> 19)) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8)); 

    return _w;
}

inline int RandGen::getIntInRange(int min, int max)
{
 return min + _next() % (max - min + 1);
}

inline float RandGen::getFloat()
{
 return _next() / 4294967295.f;
}

inline float RandGen::getFloatInRange(float min, float max)
{
 return min + getFloat() * (max - min);
}
inline void RandGen::reset(crt::uint32 seed)
{
    _x = seed;
    _y = 362436069;
    _z = 521288629;
    _w = 88675123;
}
```

Comment: Ну и чем ваше решение отличается от Random.Range с указанием seed?